# Macro to read and list file locations input by user and exit if error

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a macro that reads certain files input by a user and part of the code below collects filenames. However, when the user enters multiple file locations, only one file location is entered.

In column C, I would like an input of all the file locations in order such that they are listed as: filelocation1, filelocaction2...and so on.

This is my current code:

```
Sub openfiles()

    Dim Files As Variant

    'open directory, filter by excel files, select files and place in array
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
        FileFilter:="Excel Filter (*.xlsx), *.xlsx", _
        MultiSelect:=True)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'update in background

    If not IsArray(Files) Then
        MsgBox "No files selected. Cannot continue."
        Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = "no files selected"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Files
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the `SelectedFiles` a typo?

Comment: As pointed out by @BigBen you are declaring Files, assigning to SelectedFiles, and then checking the value of Files. Use Option Explicit to avoid these issues before they begin.

Comment: @Warcupine Alas, by default in fresh Office installation the `Option Explicit` is turned off... That is how people get bad habits 

Comment: Disregarding the clear typo-the reason this is happening is your `Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = Files`. Basically saying, go to the end of "O", then down 1 and with this range (its only 1 cell at this point) insert my array of files.  It can only HOLD one value from the array since there is only 1 cell.  Change it to `Range(Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), Range("O" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(UBound(Files) - LBound(Files) + 1, 0)) = Files`. This will get the last cell in "O", move down 1 and then get the range based on how many items are in the file array.